# Not able to upload UIImage to server in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I have been trying to upload UIImage on the server,but before uploading i have been converting it to BASE64 string.The method is POST and i am sending the image with other parameters in body.Have read several answers related to this but didn't get anything useful.
Here is my code

```
-(void)makeprofileWithData:(NSString *)urlstring andname:(NSString *)name gender:(NSString *)gender withstatus:(NSString *)status latitide:(NSString *)lat withLongitude:(NSString *)longitude andaddress:(NSString *)address andImage:(NSString *)string;
{

    appdel=(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",appdel.bseurl,urlstring]];
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    NSString *tempString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mobile=%@&name=%@&gender=%@&status=%@&address=%@&latitude=%@&longitude=%@&profile_pic=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"mobile"],name,gender,status,address,lat,longitude,string];


    NSData *requestData = [tempString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: request delegate:self];
}
```

In this method the **string** is the BASE64 string,and i am sending other parameters like mobile,name location,address ,gender also in the body separated by &.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest instead of BASE64 conversion you can use GZiP Compression. It will give better result. You can download sample project from here 
[Here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP)

You can use GZIP class from Compression and uncompression.

Comment: can you tell me what i am doing wrong in above code

Comment: I think you doing well according to me but problem is on your server side they not properly decode it. Tell them you use BASE64 conversion. They decode accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a problem with your UTF8 encoding; can you check the result of

```
- (BOOL)canBeConvertedToEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

in your code to clear away that possibility.